# Grails FindAll Order By not working HQL

Tags: hibernate, grails, sql-order-by, hql, findall

When I write this hql :

```
tempDocs = Document.findAll("FROM Document where docName LIKE :docn ORDER BY status asc",[docn:string],[max:limit, offset:startIndex])
```

is works proper.
But when I am trying to generalize it by writing

```
tempDocs = Document.findAll("FROM Document where docName LIKE :docn",[docn:string],[max:limit, offset:startIndex,sort:column,order:ordering])
```

This does not seem to give the correct ordering. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Were you able to try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for [findAll](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAll.html), you only have three options for queryParams: max, offset, cache. As a hybrid between your two examples, you could supply sort and order as named parameters.

```
tempDocs = Document.findAll("FROM Document where docName LIKE :docn ORDER BY :sort :order",[docn:string],[max:limit, offset:startIndex,sort:column,order:ordering])
```

Answer (score 0):

for me th3morg's solution caused the following exception:

Class
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException
Message
    unexpected token: : near line 1, column 89 [FROM receiptbucketserver.Receipt where project.customer.id = :customerId ORDER BY :sort :order]

my syntax looked like this (which might be wrong, i am not an expert)
    Receipt.findAll("FROM Receipt where project.customer.id = :customerId ORDER BY :sort :order",[customerId:customer.id],[sort:column,order:ordering])

i was able to get it working with an very ugly looking :

```
Receipt.findAll("from Receipt as r where r.project.customer.id = :companyId ORDER BY " +  field + " " + sortOrder   , [companyId: customer.id] )
```

called by:

```
def listReceipts = receiptHelperService.getReceiptsByCustomer(customerInstance, "vendor", "desc")
```